# Integrate $\int_a^b e^{- \cos(t)} dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

I am looking for an explicit representation of $\int_a^b e^{- \cos(t)} dt$. The only way I could imagine to find the antiderivative is to expand this function in spherical harmonics or use the taylor series. But as I was often quite impressed with what people came up here, there might be something better we can do about it?

Comment: I doubt one exists.

Comment: When you say "explicit representation" does that mean an analytical solution or algebraic?

Comment: Let's put it that way: All functions that have their own article at mathworld are okay and the answer should not contain limits (so especially no series or infinite products). So even a hypergeometric function would be okay, although this one is defined as a series itself.

Comment: Through series, which you forbid, the answer is quite easy to obtain. About $0$,
$$e^{-\cos t}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!}\cos^nt$$
Integrating gives:
$$\int^n_a e^{-\cos t}dt=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int^b_a\cos^ntdt$$
You can now use the reduction formula to evaluate it.

Comment: Yes, but this is especially what I don't want.

Comment: Risch algorithm returns nothing with your anti derivative. Seeing as your original integral is still technically indefinite, it does not look good for a representation. Maybe if you tell us why you need it we can make the problem more focused.

Answer (score 0):

The primitive of the function you mentioned cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more details. However, if *a* and *b* are multiples of $\dfrac\pi2$ , then the *definite* integral *can* be expressed in terms of *special* $\big($non-elementary$\big)$ functions, such as [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) or [Struve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).